# Specify task timeout in parallel linq to objects

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, linq-to-objects

I have a list of Pictures that I want to process in parallel, but with a timeout.  My old code did this by paging through the items and using WaitHandles, but I want to use the new Parallel Linq or Tasks library available in .Net 4.

The following snippet is working, how do I add a timeout to it? (Timeout would be for each task executing, not a timeout for all items to be processed)

```
   private PictureList FetchPictures(List<Picture> wallResults) 
   {                
            wallResults
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
                .ForAll(delegate(Picture p){
```

Comment: Did you check out CancellationTokenSource and cancel after a timeout using timers? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691.aspx

Comment: @seshuk - Please see the comment I left on svick's answer, I believe it applies to your link as well since they both involve CancellationToken's.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`WithCancellation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413259) for that:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);

wallResults
    .AsParallel()
    .WithCancellation(cts.Token)
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
    .ForAll(p => { …
```

If you can't use .Net 4.5, you won't be able to use timeout-accepting constructor of `CancellationTokenSource`, so you'll have to use `Timer` manually.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however from what I can tell this isn't what I'm looking for. "Timeout would be for each task executing, not a timeout for all items to be processed."  From what I've read the cancellation toke is a way to cancel the ForAll operation as a whole, and does not give you the granularity to specify that a single item should be canceled after a certain amount of time. Please correct me if I've misread the MSDN documentation/your answer.

Comment: Oh, I must have overlooked that part in parentheses in your question. In that case, this has nothing to do with PLINQ and will depend completely on what code you're running inside the `ForAll()` delegate.