# Read Degree Of Parallelism in PLinq extension method

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, extension-methods, plinq

I'm considering making my own PLinq extension method to provide the feature described in my recent question: [Specify task timeout in parallel linq to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158360/specify-task-timeout-in-parallel-linq-to-objects). I'd like to reuse as much existing .Net structure as I can, including any code that may already be specifying a Degree of Parallelism on the PLinq query.

In the below code block I'm specifying a degree of parallelism. Assuming that CustomForAll is a custom PLinq extension method with the same signature as the existing ForAll method, how would I read the degree of parallelism specified on the TSource?

```
private PictureList FetchPictures(List<Picture> wallResults) 
{                
        wallResults
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
            .CustomForAll(delegate(Picture p){
```

Comment: Why can't you use the standard `ForAll` implementation?

Comment: @ReedCopsey - I want to implement per task timeouts, rather then a cancellation token that spans all tasks (see the comments on my linked question).

Comment: Just build it into the `Action<Picture>` itself, and use ForAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't a supported operation.  PLINQ was not designed in a manner that allows for third party extensions, without reverting to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The degree of parallelism is stored within the [ParallelQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelquery.aspx) class in a private member variable (`private QuerySettings m_specifiedSettings`, in the `int? m_degreeOfParallism` field).

You could, potentially, use reflection to extract that, but it's an internal implementation detail that's subject to change.